# Create Quote with image in Microsoft Word

Tags: microsoft-word, text-editors

I'd like to create indent text with image.
[image]

and create the new style for reuse it.
In create/modify style I didn't find any option about it.
I'm using word for mac osx Version. 16.32

Thanks

Comment: Changing the image text-wrapping property should achieve this without needing to do any customized formatting?  Or maybe I'm misunderstanding what you mean.

Comment: @Arctiic thanks, But each time that I want to use the quote I must to copy paste.
I'd like to create style in style panel